# Анимация вспышки

Tags: css, css-animation

Делаю анимация открытия сундука, и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не знаю как сделать вспышку при открытии сундука. Идея такая, когда открывается сундук, идёт небольшая вспышка, которая скрывает то, что там находится, и соответственно, потом исчезает вспышка через секунды 2-3.Вспышка лучше с какими нибудь бликами.

Просто надо сделать появление и исчезновение вспышки(белой).

Comment: В моём понимании вспышка это просто `opacity` задержкой. 
Скажите, вам нужна именно красивая анимация или просто вспышка?

Comment: Красивая, конечно :)

Answer (score 7):

Ну если красиво то тогда вот так

```js
var c,
    ctx,
    w,
    h,
    cx,
    cy,
    branches,
    startHue,
    tick;

function rand( min, max ) {
    return Math.random() * ( max - min ) + min;
}

function randInt( min, max ) {
    return Math.floor( min + Math.random() * ( max - min + 1 ) );
};

function Branch( hue, x, y, angle, vel ) {
    var move = 15;
    this.x = x + rand( -move, move );
    this.y = y + rand( -move, move );
    this.points = [];
    this.angle = angle != undefined ? angle : rand( 0, Math.PI * 1 );
    this.vel = vel != undefined ? vel : rand( -4, 4 );
    this.spread = 0;
    this.tick = 0;
    this.hue = hue != undefined ? hue : 200;
    this.life = 1;
    this.decay = 0.0015;
    this.dead = false;
    
    this.points.push({
        x: this.x,
        y: this.y
    });
}

Branch.prototype.step = function( i ) {
    this.life -= this.decay;
    if( this.life <= 0 ) {
        this.dead = true;   
    }
    
    if( !this.dead ) {
        var lastPoint = this.points[ this.points.length - 1 ];
        this.points.push({
            x: lastPoint.x + Math.cos( this.angle ) * this.vel,
            y: lastPoint.y + Math.sin( this.angle ) * this.vel
        });
        this.angle += rand( -this.spread, this.spread );
        this.vel *= 0.99;
        this.spread = this.vel * 0.04;
        this.tick++;
        this.hue += 0.3;
    } else {
        branches.splice( i, 1 );
    }
};

Branch.prototype.draw = function() {
    if( !this.points.length || this.dead ) {
        return false;
    }
    
    var length = this.points.length,
        i = length - 1,
        point = this.points[ i ],
        lastPoint = this.points[ i - randInt( 5, 100 ) ];
        //jitter = 8;
    if( lastPoint ) {
        var jitter = 2 + this.life * 6;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo( lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y );
        ctx.lineTo( point.x + rand( -jitter, jitter ), point.y + rand( -jitter, jitter ) );
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        var alpha = this.life * 0.075;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsla(' + ( this.hue + rand( -10, 10 ) ) + ', 70%, 40%, ' + alpha + ')';
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

function init() {
    c = document.getElementById( 'c' );
    ctx = c.getContext( '2d' );
    startHue = 220;
    branches = [];
    reset();
    loop();
}

function reset() {
    w = window.innerWidth;
    h = window.innerHeight;
    cx = w / 2;
    cy = h / 2;
    branches.length = 0;
    c.width = w;
    c.height = h;
    tick = 0;
    
    
    for( var i = 0; i < 500; i++ ) {        
        branches.push( new Branch( startHue, cx, cy) );
    }
}

function step() {
    var i = branches.length;
    while( i-- ) { branches[ i ].step( i ) }
    tick++;
}

function draw() {
    var i = branches.length;
    if( tick < 450 ) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.002;
        ctx.translate( cx, cy );
        var scale = 1 + tick * 0.00025 ;
        ctx.scale( scale, scale );
        ctx.translate( -cx, -cy );
        ctx.drawImage( c, rand( -160, 150 ), rand( -150, 150 ) );
        ctx.restore();
    }
    
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
        while( i-- ) { branches[ i ].draw() }
}

function loop() {
    requestAnimationFrame( loop );
    step();
    draw();
    step();
    draw();
}

window.addEventListener( 'resize', reset );
window.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
    startHue += 60;
    reset();
});

init();
```

```css
body {
    background: #000;
    overflow: hidden;   
}

canvas {
    display: block; 
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ничего себе, мне что нибудь по проще.Намного попроще.

Comment: Но анимация реально классная. Прям браво!